# Why isn't it possible to run a SharePoint server instance in an Azure VM role?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, azure

I often heard that it is senseless to run a SharePoint server in a Windows Azure vm role since a vm role loses its state after a reboot.

I have to admit that I only have little knowledge about SharePoint, but in what way does this affect a SharePoint server? What kind of data is stateful? User content could be delegated to a database in order to persist it, couldn't it? But what kind of data remains that is lost if the vm role reboots?

Even Microsoft says:

> This means that programs must be stateless so that data is not lost when a role fails. Applications such as SharePoint, SQL Server, Small Business Server, and Terminal Server are stateful applications that are not supported in the VM Role. The lack of UDP traffic means that a Domain Controller (Active Directory) will not work in a VM Role.

Comment: When the persistent VM role arrives it may be technically possible to do this, but make sure you check out the license agreement carefully. I suspect it might turn out to be forbidden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain that this is what Microsoft means:

When you install a "feature" in SharePoint, many of the artifacts installed do *not* live in the content database. Instead, they live in the "14-hive" (or 12-hive, depending on version). This is a series of folders on disk.

I guess that after a reboot, the content database would indicate that the feature was installed, but the disk would only have the original contents, from before the feature was installed.

Comment: Okay, but this means when I include the necessary features already in my vm role image, a reboot would not do any harm. Are those features really the only thing that makes Sharepoint stateful? I mean if the requirements in terms of features do not change over the years, I cannot see a problem and Microsoft's statement "Sharepoint not supported" sounds a bit hard.

Comment: Again, I don't **know** that this is what Microsoft means. However, keep in mind that the "SharePoint" product is meant to be extensible - that is, it's meant that one can add features to it. If one cannot add features, then they may think, "is this SharePoint"?

Comment: Even if you initially included the required files as features in your image, patching it would still be problematic as many of those files are overwritten or otherwise updated.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint needs SQL (and not SQL Azure), and both SharePoint and SQL are not stateless. They both write in registry, install stuff all other the place etc...

However, statefull VM Role in not far away now, and SharePoint will be supported.